# Body repair using non-original-manufacturer parts

Tags: subaru, body-work, part-interchange

My three-month-old Subaru Crosstrek was hit in the rear bumper. The body shop that the dealer sent me to says the damage was limited to that one part, but I notice on the estimate that they propose to use (and paint) "parts not made by the original manufacturer". I don't need to cut corners (the other guy's insurance will cover it) so I'm wondering if I should insist on genuine Subaru body parts, or if the non-original parts are entirely equivalent.

Comment: Probably an opinion-based question, but why bother?  You deserve OEM parts at the very least to preserve resale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the car is three months old then the parts should be original Subaru, not chinesium imports - ie this should be to the same standard as original Subaru to be covered by the existing, and continuing warranty.

I would expect that the dealer should be doing the repair or a body shop accredited by Subaru so that there is no issue in the future.

Comment: Good point about keeping the vehicle up to the same standard as was warranteed. As it turns out, the verbiage about non-original parts was simply a disclaimer printed on the form. If the parts listed had actually been non-original, that fact would have been individually noted.

Comment: You need to ask yourself , do I really want to hire a lawyer to fight the insurance company for a few months ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 Why not ask the dealer for a written guarantee first ...

Comment: @Chap good result then, hope they do a really nice job for you.